# ExtJS: How to set defaults for Grid columns within initComponent?

Tags: extjs, grid, set, default

as you notice below, I'm using `Ext.Array.merge` to render `columns` within `initComponent`.

I'm try to set `columns`' `flex` property as default in `initComponent`.
How can I achieve to this arrangement?

```
initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.on('resize', function () { me.height = window.innerHeight - App.MAIN_FOOTER_HEIGHT - App.MAIN_HEADER_HEIGHT - 100 });

        me.createGridMenu();

        me.columns = Ext.Array.merge(me.getListColsStart(), me.getListCols(), me.getListColsEnd());

        //I need to set through here. Any solution such as setDefaults or dot notation to fetch defaults of columns?

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
```

and here is one of overrided functions

```
getListCols: function () {
        return [];
    },
```

UPDATE: 
Related second question moved to [Setting defaults to panel items for nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171248/extjs-setting-defaults-to-panel-items-for-nested-objects) post. FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the API Docs, from the [`columns` documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#cfg-columns) (it also contains an example related to your question):

> This can also be a configuration object for a
>   Ext.grid.header.Container which may override certain default
>   configurations if necessary. For example, the special layout may be
>   overridden to use a simpler layout, **or one can set default values
>   shared by all columns**:

So, in your case, here is how you can setup `flex` as a default config for all columns:

```
me.columns = {
    items: Ext.Array.merge(
        me.getListColsStart(),
        me.getListCols(),
        me.getListColsEnd()
    ),
    defaults: {
        flex: 1
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
If the `flex` property must be applied only to a subset of columns, one way to achieve this is by applying the array [map](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.Array.html#method-map) function on the needed subset:

```
me.columns = Ext.Array.merge(
    me.getListColsStart(),
    Ext.Array.map(me.getListCols(), function(listColConfig) {
        listColConfig.flex = 1;
        return listColConfig;
    }),
    me.getListColsEnd()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer and this solution works perfectly but I just figure out that I need `flex` as default only for those columns which are rendering through `getListCols()` func. Is this possible to set defaults only for `getListCols`?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot @scebotari66

Comment: I've with a new situation, could you give any idea about that? As you advice I've used `Ext.Array.map` and worked very well. The new situation is I need to set `flex` config as default but in nested array. Could you please check out my updated question for any advice. Thanks.

Comment: There are a couple of questions that arise for this particular situation, so I would suggest you to ask a new question in order to not pollute this one.

Comment: thanks for opinion; moved to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171248/extjs-setting-defaults-to-panel-items-for-nested-objects