# ExtJS: Setting defaults to panel items for nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, extjs, defaults

This question is part of [How to set defaults for Grid columns within initComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969190/extjs-how-to-set-defaults-for-grid-columns-within-initcomponent) and posted here independently through @scebotari66 advice on main post.

As you'll notice below; there is `Ext.Array.map` to define `defaults` for related function.

```
// Statment
    initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;
    me.items = Ext.Array.merge(
        me.getFormSt(),
        Ext.Array.map(me.getForm(), function (listFldConfig) { //Aim to using the array map function to set flex property for subset fields
            listFldConfig.flex = 1;
            return listFldConfig;
        }),
        me.getFormEnd()
    );
    me.callParent(arguments)
},

// Implementation
getForm: function () {
        var me = this;
        var form = [
            { // Array.map func. sets `flex` to this obj.
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                layout: { type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch', pack: 'start' },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'foofield',
                                //flex: 1 //But I need to set `flex` as default for this obj. in nested items array
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'barfield',
                                //flex: 1 //But I need to set `flex` as default for this obj. in nested items array
                            }
```

The thing is this implementation is works as expected but on this situation I'm creating a `fieldcontainer` object which is include all other things and items inside. And `Array.map` sets `flex` config only to first `fieldcontainer` obj. I need to define `flex` config only for nested `items` which has `foofield` and `barfield`.

Comment: instead of using `map` function you can directly [`defaults:{flex:1}`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.Container.html#cfg-defaults)  config for inner `fieldcontainer` that contain `foofield` and `barfield`.

Comment: But I'm creating tons of that kind of nested `fieldcontainer`s and `items` . There fore trying to avoid DRY and figure out some other useful approach.

Comment: so there is one more useful approach you can create custom component and you can use once to it will more easy

Comment: dear @NarendraJadhav just the thing! Even I've official release of Sencha SDK; `Ext.form.FieldContainer` is not in SDK source!? Why is that? I've stated `extend: 'Ext.form.FieldContainer'` but can not find declaration and throws error; `[ERR] Failed to resolve dependency Ext.form.FieldContainer for file`

Comment: which version of extjs your are using  ?

Comment: @NarendraJadhav It's `6.5.3.57`

Comment: @NarendraJadhav solved. Toolkit related issue! I've created the file/class under `app` folder and after moving the file/class to `classic` folder solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through @NarendraJadhav 's opinion; created my own structure...

Definition;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.BaseFldCon', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FieldContainer',
    xtype: 'basefldcon'
});

Ext.define('MyApp.VBoxFldCon', {
    extend: 'MyApp.BaseFldCon',
    xtype: 'vboxfldcon',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch',
        pack: 'start'
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.HBoxFldCon', {
    extend: 'MyApp.BaseFldCon',
    xtype: 'hboxfldcon',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    defaults: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

Implementation;

```
{
   xtype: 'vboxfldcon',
   items: [
            {
              xtype: 'hboxfldcon',
              items: [
                       {
                           xtype: 'foofield',
                        },
                        {
                           xtype: 'barfield'
                        },
                        {
                           xtype: 'foocombo'
                        }
                     ]
             },
```

Answer (score 2):

Defaults are defined using the [`defaults`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.container.Container.html#cfg-defaults) config on containers:

```
xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
layout: 'hbox',
defaults: {
    flex: 1
},
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'foofield',
    },
    {
        xtype: 'barfield',
    }
```

To cover nested containers, you can nest multiple `defaults` configs inside each other:

```
defaults: {
    defaults: {
        flex: 1
    },
    flex: 1
}
```

Please note that an `xtype` config as part of the `defaults` object can lead to undesired results, and that you should use the [`defaultType`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.container.Container.html#cfg-defaultType) config to define the default type of child elements of a container.

Comment: I've always used `xtype` inside `defaults` and didn't have any problems so far. Can you think of a case where there are issues regarding using this approach?

Comment: @scebotari66 Yes, I had issues with that in 2014/2015, but I don't remember the details. Only that Sencha Support told me to use `defaultType` instead which then fixed the issue.

Comment: You answer helped me. Can I please ask you what the propery 'flex' means? Perhaps you have some example?

Comment: @FrenkyB Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-flex)? If you have inside a `hbox` layout three components with `flex: 1`,  `flex: .5` and `flex: 3`, then the first component will be twice as wide as the second and the third is three times as wide as the first (= six times as wide as the second).